# After Downloading app from google play store getting crashed?

Tags: android, google-play, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

My app is working fine when I build it from android studio. But the app is getting crashed when I download it from play store.
Kindly find the attached crashlytics report in which the error is focused.[image]

Below is my `build.gradle` file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "igpl.gfee.com.gfee"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            multiDexEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.scottyab:showhidepasswordedittext:0.8'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1'
    //implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.budiyev.android:code-scanner:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:1.3.0'

    // implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.1.0@aar'
    //gson
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    //Retrofit and RxJava Integration
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
    //gson and retrofit integration
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.0'
    implementation 'com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1'


    //ButterKnife
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.github.silvestrpredko:dot-progress-bar:1.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Below is my `androidmanifest` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="igpl.gfee.com.gfee">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/gfee_logo_new"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/gfee_logo_new"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:testOnly="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:icon,android:theme">

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Fragments.WorkSpace"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Fragments.MainSurvey"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Fragments.MainActivites.CreateOrganization"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Fragments.MainActivites.AddressFragment"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Fragments.MainActivites.CreateGroup"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Fragments.Profile"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".QRScanner"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".GoalDashBoard"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ProjectDashBoard"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MileStoneDashBoard"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".TaskDetailsDashBoard"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MeetingDashBoard"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".FingerprintActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Fragments.EditProfile"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".WebRemote"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".VersionNumber"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ChangePassword"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity android:name=".Fragments.MainActivites.OrganizationsListData"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

        <activity android:name=".Fragments.MainActivites.OrganizationDashBoard"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>

        <activity android:name=".Fragments.MainActivites.GroupDashBoard"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>

        <activity android:name=".Fragments.MainActivites.GroupsListData"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".SurveyActivities.CreateSurvey"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity android:name=".Fragments.Survey.SurveyinfoScreens"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

        <activity android:name=".Fragments.Survey.Survey_PaidInfoScreens"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".Utils.TempActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="262e4ef469d58d4188b4f4c8169fd4e4fe1417a3" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/splash_logo" />
        <!--
            <activity
            android:name=".Fragments.Main2Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main2"></activity>
        -->

        <receiver android:name=".BoardcastReceiver.IncomingSms">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name=".FCM.FirebaseDataReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name=".FCM.MyBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".FCM.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".FCM.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".Fragments.MainActivites.OrganizationDetails"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_scrolling"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"></activity>

        <activity android:name=".Fragments.MainActivites.OrganizationSummary"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name=".Fragments.MainActivites.ImageZoomActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: might be because `proguard` obfuscated that class

Comment: have you implemented any Referal Service?

Comment: what steps you followed to use InstallReferrerReceiver ?

Comment: I didnt use any referal service.

Comment: @ManojPerumarath you want me to remove proguard?

Comment: @SunilP Your app is crashing after installing from play store because when you install any app from play store, an Install Referrer Broadcast is received. If you are not using any referrer service, do check any broadcast receiver registered in the app Manifest. Also, make sure if any recently added library has this receiver. You can check this in the merged manifest.

Comment: @RishabhSagar Yes i have registered FCM boardcast receivers in androidmanifest file.

Comment: @SunilP can you add the manifest file here?

Comment: I have added @RishabhSagar

Comment: @SunilP I added an answer regarding this issue

Comment: Not a good practice to remove proguard, only remove from the above mentioned class

Comment: remove proguard, do not use minify and make app bundles and let playstore sign it.

Comment: In the merged manifest, can you find `play-services-measurement-impl` manifest?

Answer (score 1):

`AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver` class is part of `firebase-core` library.

The error says that the `AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver` class is not found in the dex path. This means the version you are using doesn't contain the specified class.

From the Manifest, we can see that you are using `firebase-core` version of `10.0.1`. Update the `firebase-core` to `17.0.1` and `firebase-messaging` to `19.0.1`.

Test it from the ADB or release it in the on the Play Store to test it.

Comment: when i change the versions of my firebase-core and firebase-messaging I am getting below error

`tools:replace specified at line:19 for attribute android:appComponentFactory, but no new value specified app main manifest`

`Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs  at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.mergeManifestsForApplication`

Comment: Can you try (`firebase-core`) with `16.0.8` and (`firebase-messaging`) `18.0.0`

Comment: ya it worked without any error. but let me try on my primary bug after publishing the app in play store.

Comment: Thanks @Srikar Reddy after changing firebase to 16.0.8 and firebase-messaging to 18.0.0 it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

**Disable R8 code shrinker and update on playstore**

```
go to->gradle.properties
add -> android.enableR8 = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this receiver from the Manifest, if you are not using this.

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: I am not using it. I have just added it because of the error which I facing but it didnt helped me. Ok i will remove

Comment: So you want me to remove that and check

Comment: @SunilP yes, remove this receiver and upload the APK to play store. This will work for sure.

Comment: Ok i have removed it. But it still remains as the previous I think again same error will I face?

Comment: If you want to check without uploading it to play store, you can try to send the broadcast using ADB.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197655/discussion-between-sunil-p-and-rishabh-sagar).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because of `minifyEnabled false`.
You can apply the release mode rules to debug mode and check.

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            multiDexEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            multiDexEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Comment: let me try @bhavesh